# How to remove minutes button from Materual UI datetime picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I am trying to customize a datetimepicker of materialUI in ReactJS. I do not want the user to be able to see or select minutes in the picker. I have set the views prop to year month date and hours but the user can still click on minutes from the toolbar. How can I hide minutes from the toolbar. This is the code for the component

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <DateTimePicker
    required
    label="Start Date and Time"
    inputVariant="outlined"
    value={SelectedFromDate}
    onChange={(value) => handleSelectedFromDate(value)}
    fullWidth
    margin="dense"
    disablePast
    format="do MMMM yyyy HH:mm"
    openTo={'year'}
    views={['year', 'month', 'date', 'hours',]}
    ampm={false}  
    allowKeyboardControl={true}
    hideTabs
    disableToolbar={false}
    minutesStep={60}
    disabled={!(checkName && checkFile)}
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

and this is how it looks currently

[image]

Comment: Do you need the time, or would the DatePicker be a better option?

Comment: @Corporalis I need date and hours and don't need minutes

Answer (score 1):

I think format is a problem. Can you try changing:

```
format="do MMMM yyyy HH:mm"
```

to:

```
format="do MMMM yyyy HH"
```

Comment: this hides minutes from the text field but I want to hide them from the toolbar